# PIP install Wheel file works but not tar file for the same version of same package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.6

PIP install of pandas 0.24.2 package through wheel file is working fine, but installing pandas through the tarball for the same version is failing. Please help.

I have a Linux machine where I try to install pandas 0.24.2 version using wheel file and the installation is successful. However, when I try to install pandas 0.24.2 version using its tarball file fails. Is tarball not an alternate for wheel file? My understanding is tarball has the source code of package, where as wheel file is binary containing the compiled version of the package. Am I missing anything here? I have python 3.6.6 and tried using manylinux1_x86_64 version of pandas wheel & tar file.

Comment: Please show us the error you're getting, it's awfully hard to help if all we know is "it's failing".

Comment: Your understanding is correct, though: .whls are zips containing precompiled binaries for a given architecture. Building from the source tarballs requires an environment in which the library can be built, including a working compiler, libraries, etc.